# Calling the same method from multiple buttons

Tags: android

How can I write complete code for each button like I did for button1? 
I want the same method to be called from multiple buttons as for button1.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    one.setOnClickListener(this); // calling onClick() method

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String phoneNumber = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editView4)).getText().toString();

    try {
        {
            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "A", null, null);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        dialog.show();

    }
}


public void Openinformation(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.information);
}
}
```

Comment: what you want to do exactly??? Do you want same method to be called from multiple buttons or wat??

Comment: yes iwant same method to be called from multiple buttons but each button will send different message like button 1 sends A button 2 sends B and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same as you did for other buttons:

```
Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
one.setOnClickListener(this); // calling onClick() method
Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
two.setOnClickListener(this); // calling the same onClick()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have the buttons all use the same `OnClickListener` and then check which view was clicked to determine which message to send

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String phoneNumber = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editView4)).getText().toString();

    try {
        String message;
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            message = "A";
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
            message = "B";
        }

        SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        dialog.show();

    }
}
```